# vertical swiper-slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

i have vertical swiper-slider, this is what my configurations looks like:

```
var swiper2 = new Swiper('.s2', {
 
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  slidesPerColumn: 4,
 
      spaceBetween: 30, // Adjust spacing between slides if needed
      autoplay: {
        delay: 3000, // Autoplay interval in milliseconds
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ' .swiper2-button-next',
        prevEl: '  .swiper2-button-prev',
      },
    
});
```

when i have sliderPerView set as auto, it shows all my slides at one page and i dont want that. i want to have 4 slides in each column, but when i set sliderPerView to 1, it adds adds odd behavior to the slider, for example it starts flickering and sets height of slides like this:
[image]

i tried googling and even used openai to solve it but nothing worked, my current version is little old but i tried version 10 and the result was same. any ideas?